# iPhone + SQLite3 + fetch date column

Tags: iphone, date, sqlite, fetch

I am having a date column in my table and I want to fetch that in iPhone application, I use following method to fetch values:

objPlayer.type = sqlite3_column_int(selectstmt, 1);

Now I can't find something like sqlite3_column_date.

Which is the method I can use for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sqlite3_column_text()` since `sqlite3_column_date()` is the [same](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/tktview?tn=2120,39).